# Integrate Paytm PGSDK_V2.0 Android

Tags: android, paytm

I am Integrating `Paytm PGSDK_V2.0` in my android app. I have read all documentation  on [Github](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit). I have understand everything.but the problem is in its earlier SDK where we can simply generate checksum using `Paytm Merchant` object Like:

```
PaytmMerchant merchant=new PaytmMerchant("Checksum generation url","Checksum verification url");
```

and put this in Service Like this

```
 Service.initialize(Order,merchant,null);
```

But in new SDK it change to

```
 Service.initialize(Order,null);
```

So please help me how to generate checksum in new SDK

Comment: Have a look at example in the library https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit/blob/master/SampleMerchantApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/merchantapp/MerchantActivity.java  there he says in comment   `//Kindly create complete Map and checksum on your server side and then put it here in paramMap`

Comment: For more reference visit link given here https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit/issues/11

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Paytm has change process to increase the security. now in PGSDK_V2.0 first you have to generate through calling the api `Checksum Generation` on your server side
Like this:

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            url ="http://xxx.co.in/generateChecksum.php";
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(MainActivity.this);

                param="ORDER_ID=" + orderId+
                        "&MID="+YourMID+
                        "&CUST_ID="+custId+
                        "&CHANNEL_ID=WAP&INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail110&WEBSITE=xxxwap&TXN_AMOUNT="+billAmt+"&CALLBACK_URL=http://xxx.co.in/verifyChecksum.php";

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST",param);
            Log.e("CheckSum result >>",jsonObject.toString());
            if(jsonObject != null){
                Log.d("CheckSum result >>",jsonObject.toString());
                try {

                    CHECKSUMHASH=jsonObject.has("CHECKSUMHASH")?jsonObject.getString("CHECKSUMHASH"):"";
                    Log.e("CheckSum result >>",CHECKSUMHASH);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

now after getting `CHECKSUM` string in your `onPostExecute` initialize paytm Service object and do further process Like This:

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressDialog.hide();
            Service = PaytmPGService.getProductionService();

    /*PaytmMerchant constructor takes two parameters
    1) Checksum generation url
    2) Checksum verification url
    Merchant should replace the below values with his values*/




            //below parameter map is required to construct PaytmOrder object, Merchant should replace below map values with his own values

            Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            //these are mandatory parameters


            paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", orderId);
            //MID provided by paytm

            paramMap.put("MID", yourMID);
            paramMap.put("CUST_ID", custId);
            paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
            paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
            paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "xxxwap");
            paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT",billAmt);
            // 
            paramMap.put("CALLBACK_URL" ,"http://xxx.co.in/verifyChecksum.php");
            paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH" ,CHECKSUMHASH);
            PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);



            Service.initialize(Order,null);
            Service.startPaymentTransaction(ReviewBooking.this, true, true, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage) {
                    // Some UI Error Occurred in Payment Gateway Activity.
                    // // This may be due to initialization of views in
                    // Payment Gateway Activity or may be due to //
                    // initialization of webview. // Error Message details
                    // the error occurred.
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction : " + inResponse);
                    String response=inResponse.getString("RESPMSG");
                    if (response.equals("Txn Successful."))
                    {
                        new ConfirmMerchent().execute();
                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Payment Transaction response "+inResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                @Override
                public void networkNotAvailable() {
                    // If network is not
                    // available, then this
                    // method gets called.
                }

                @Override
                public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String inErrorMessage) {
                    // This method gets called if client authentication
                    // failed. // Failure may be due to following reasons //
                    // 1. Server error or downtime. // 2. Server unable to
                    // generate checksum or checksum response is not in
                    // proper format. // 3. Server failed to authenticate
                    // that client. That is value of payt_STATUS is 2. //
                    // Error Message describes the reason for failure.
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode,
                                                  String inErrorMessage, String inFailingUrl) {

                }

                // had to be added: NOTE
                @Override
                public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionCancel(String inErrorMessage, Bundle inResponse) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction Failed " + inErrorMessage);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Payment Transaction Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

**JsonParser Class**

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    // variable to hold context
    private Context context;
    // constructor
    public JSONParser(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }


    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,String method,String params) {

       // boolean isReachable =Config.isURLReachable(context);
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            String retSrc="";
            char current = '0';

                URL url1 = new URL(url);
                // check for request method
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
               urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.getBytes().length);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                out.print(params);
                out.close();
            }
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];
                StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
                int numRead = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    x.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
                }
                retSrc=x.toString();



            jObj = new JSONObject(retSrc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Connectivity issue. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return null;
        }finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

and parameter values should be same both time.

Comment: Hi Ghanshyam, Can you please provide your JSONParser class please.

Comment: Means response in Json format which i getting from server @Naveen

Comment: What exactly JSONParser is [In doInBackground()] ?

Comment: Thanks Ghanshyam, can you explain please about param in doInBackGround() ?

Comment: In `Params `, `OrderId` is a random Int id which you generate for every order.  `MID` is Merchant id which is provided to every merchant by paytm.  `CUST_ID` is customer id which you use to identify every customer. you can use here customer  `email id` for example.  `CHANNEL_ID ` is WAP for mobile platform.  `INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID `  this is also provided by Paytm  to each merchant. `WEBSITE ` is also provided by Paytm. `TXN_AMOUNT` is `bill amount ` ANd `CALLBACK_URL`  is `verify checksum` url  @Naveen

Comment: Thanks Ghanshyam you are very helpful, Can you please provide the MainActivity where doInBackGround in present ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146832/discussion-between-ghanshyam-sharma-and-naveen).

Comment: Hi Ghanshyam,can you please provide ConfirmMerchent class please

Answer (score 4):

Generating Checksum is quite easy.

- Just get the Paytm App Checksum Kit from Github.
- Extract the downloaded kit and put it in your server. If you are using a local server using xampp then the path would be c:/xampp/htdocs/paytm. I would recommend renaming the folder name to paytm or a small name.
- Inside the kit there is a folder named lib. Inside this folder you will find a file named **config_paytm.php**, Open this file and put your Paytm Merchant Key here.
- Now you can use the file generateChecksum.php to generate checksum.
- Remember you need to pass every parameter that you will pass with transaction.
- Below you can see a retrofit api code sample to send POST request to **generateChecksum.php**.

  ```
  //this is the URL of the paytm folder that we added in the server
  //make sure you are using your ip else it will not work 
  String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.101.1/paytm/";

  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("generateChecksum.php")
  Call<Checksum> getChecksum(
          @Field("MID") String mId,
          @Field("ORDER_ID") String orderId,
          @Field("CUST_ID") String custId,
          @Field("CHANNEL_ID") String channelId,
          @Field("TXN_AMOUNT") String txnAmount,
          @Field("WEBSITE") String website,
          @Field("CALLBACK_URL") String callbackUrl,
          @Field("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID") String industryTypeId
  );
  ```

This part is very important you have to send all the parameters. And order_id should be unique everytime.

Source: **[Paytm Integration in Android Example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/paytm-integration-android-example/)**

Comment: can we do this in android device not on server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass only 8 param for checksum generation from SDK 2.0 and later. On Earlier version you need to pass email and mobile number too. Now there is no use of these param. First upload PHP file on your server and change the merchant key on config.php file inside lib folder. Now from android use can use retrofit or volley or httpconnection request to get checksum from your server. Here i am using Httpconnection (in this code JSONParse is a separate java class to call httpconnection).  You can get reference on this link -http://www.blueappsoftware.in/android/blog/paytm-integration-sdk-2-1-android/

```
public class sendUserDetailTOServerdd extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(checksum.this);

    private String orderId , mid, custid, amt;
    String url ="http://www.blueappsoftware.com/payment/payment_paytm/generateChecksum.php";
    String varifyurl = // "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<ORDER_ID>"; //
                         "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp";//
    String CHECKSUMHASH ="";

            @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();

       // initOrderId();
        orderId ="KK100343";  // NOTE :  order id must be unique
        mid = "blueap01867059473586";  // CREATI42545355156573
        custid = "KKCUST0342";

    }

    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... alldata) {

        // String  url ="http://xxx.co.in/generateChecksum.php";

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(checksum.this);
        String  param=
                "MID="+mid+
                "&ORDER_ID=" + orderId+
                "&CUST_ID="+custid+
                "&CHANNEL_ID=WEB&TXN_AMOUNT=100&WEBSITE=www.blueappsoftware.in"+"&CALLBACK_URL="+ varifyurl+"&INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail";

        Log.e("checksum"," param string "+param );



        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST",param);
        // yaha per checksum ke saht order id or status receive hoga..
        Log.e("CheckSum result >>",jsonObject.toString());
        if(jsonObject != null){
            Log.e("CheckSum result >>",jsonObject.toString());
            try {

                CHECKSUMHASH=jsonObject.has("CHECKSUMHASH")?jsonObject.getString("CHECKSUMHASH"):"";
                Log.e("CheckSum result >>",CHECKSUMHASH);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return CHECKSUMHASH;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // jab run kroge to yaha checksum dekhega
        ///ab service ko call krna hai
        Log.e(" setup acc ","  signup result  " + result);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }}
```

Step 2) now onPostExceute method you have checksum as result. It's time to call  paytm staging service and call start transaction. Below is code to call paytm service

```
 PaytmPGService Service =PaytmPGService.getStagingService();
       // when app is ready to publish use production service
        // PaytmPGService  Service = PaytmPGService.getProductionService();

        // now call paytm service here
        //below parameter map is required to construct PaytmOrder object, Merchant should replace below map values with his own values
        Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //these are mandatory parameters
        // ye sari valeu same hon achaiye

        //MID provided by paytm
        paramMap.put("MID", mid);
        paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", orderId);
        paramMap.put("CUST_ID", custid);
        paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WEB");
        paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "100");
        paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "www.blueappsoftware.in");
        paramMap.put("CALLBACK_URL" ,varifyurl);
        //paramMap.put( "EMAIL" , "abc@gmail.com");   // no need
       // paramMap.put( "MOBILE_NO" , "9144040888");  // no need
        paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH" ,CHECKSUMHASH);
        //paramMap.put("PAYMENT_TYPE_ID" ,"CC");    // no need
        paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");

        PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);

        Log.e("checksum ", paramMap.toString());


        Service.initialize(Order,null);
        // start payment service call here
        Service.startPaymentTransaction(checksum.this, true, true, checksum.this  );
```

Answer (score -1):

what is new ConfirmMerchent().execute();
and in docs 
 after merchent verify check again this uri for payment confirmation
https://secure.paytm.in/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/TXNSTATUS